# Different DNS lookup results for dig, nslookup, telnet and curl

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm having a weird disagreement between a bunch of tools on my Debian 7 box about the IP adress a certain domain name should resolve to:

```
$ dig www.ip-camera-beveiliging.com
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ip-camera-beveiliging.com. 60 IN    A   85.17.33.164

$ nslookup www.ip-camera-beveiliging.com
[...]
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.ip-camera-beveiliging.com
Address: 85.17.33.164

$ telnet www.ip-camera-beveiliging.com 80
Trying 50.57.203.17...
Connected to www.ip-camera-beveiliging.com.

$ curl -v http://www.ip-camera-beveiliging.com/
* About to connect() to www.ip-camera-beveiliging.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 50.57.203.17...
```

The first two results are what I expect, the second two results give me some sleazy ad page. I would love to understand how this happens.

**edit**: I ran `apt-get upgrade` an hour ago, and `nscd` was among the upgraded packages. I restartet nscd and the problem went away. Thank you Michael for the suggestion!

Comment: What changes did you make in the last two days?

Comment: I ran apt-get update && apt-get upgrade an hour ago, apart from that, none to any system configuration file. I'm going to look at what packages were upgraded now.

Comment: The first two ask nameservers to do the lookups. The second two use local name resolution so will check things like the hosts file, any name caches etc before hitting the name servers the system is configured to use. Do `dig localhost` and you will get NXDOMAIN while `ping localhost` will ping 127.0.0.1 for the same reason.

Comment: @Brian You da man, dawg!  Stale `/etc/hosts` 'twas!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... [nscd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd) is the Name service caching daemon. The inconsistency you see in results was likely caused by stale/cached lookups.

Are you *sure* you need to be running nscd? If you don't use it, your lookups will with your DNS servers and I think you'll get better results. Consider turning nscd off if you don't have a reason to have it enabled.

Comment: The box is sort-of-managed, I have root access but the hoster did the initial system install, so unless nscd is running by default in Debian (which I doubt), I don't know why it is. I'm going to ask.

Comment: It's possible to also tune nscd configuration settings and cache lifetimes, but I'd lean more towards disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

This question dates back to 2014. However, in latest distribution with `systemd` configured, try to flush `systemd-resolved`

```
systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```